# SoapUI get response but not the .Net Client

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, wcf-behaviour

I am trying to access a https Java webservice from .net client but always end up with "504 Gateway Timeout" exception.

I could get the response from the same webservice using SoapUI.

I also noticed that the request soap message of SoapUI and .net client aren't similar. My question is, does the wrong format of message gives the "504 Gateway Timeout" problem ? if yest, How could i modify the soap message in .net client?

Here are the request soap message that two different app generates:

SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://company.domain.com/EchoService/v1_00">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <v1:Echo>test</v1:Echo>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

.NET client

```
{<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Echo</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7a76925d-5bf0-4f2d-a9c5-c5a026e1eefb</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Echo xmlns="http://company.domain.com/EchoService/v1_00">test</Echo>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>}
```

Comment: might be something to do with the soap headers, can you post your client code, and wcf contract

Comment: What binding are you using in your client config to consume the Java web service. Please do post your code on how you are consuming the service? Try to conform to Basic Profile 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, folks nothing to do with wcf binding or soap message but the proxy was blocking the request. SoapUI could send/receive the message because it doesn't use proxy. just changed `useDefaultWebProxy="false"` in binding section of configuration.